# Solve the PDE $(3x+y-z)p+(x+y-z)q=2(z-y)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**Question:** Solve the PDE $(3x+y-z)p+(x+y-z)q=2(z-y)$ by Lagrange's method of Solution.

**Progress:** Lagrange's auxiliary equations are. 
$$\dfrac{dx}{3x+y-z}=\dfrac{dy}{x+y-z}=\dfrac{dz}{2(z-y)}$$ The three ratios are equal to $\dfrac{-dx+3dy+dz}{0}$. So we have $-dx+3dy+dz=0\implies x-3y-z=C_1$. How can I find the other one. It is given that other solution is $\dfrac{x-y+z}{\sqrt{x+y-z}}=C_2$.
How can I find this?

Answer (score 2):

We can find that,

$$\text{Each ratio} = \frac{dx-dy+dz}{2x-2y+2z} = \frac{dx+dy-dz}{4x+4y-4z}$$

or

$$\frac{d(x-y+z)}{x-y+z} = \frac{d(x+y-z)}{2(x+y-z)}$$

On integrating,

$$\ln(x-y+z) = \frac{1}{2}\ln(x+y-z) +\ln C_2 \implies C_2 = \frac{x-y+z}{\sqrt{x+y-z}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{dx}{3x+y-z}=\dfrac{dy}{x+y-z}=\dfrac{dz}{2(z-y)}$$
Substitute $w=y-z$
$$\dfrac{dx}{3x+w}=\dfrac{dw}{x+3w}$$
Rewrite as:
$$\dfrac{d(x+w)}{2(x+w)}=\dfrac{d(x-w)}{(x-w)}$$
Inegrate.